# Any laws governing the mode of recieving of information about changes in EULA or terms of services?

Tags: eula

Is there any legal obligation to inform the users about any changes in the privacy or terms of service or EULA?

For example, I add a clause that decompiling is not permitted in the EULA is just updating it on the official page of EULA enough or do I have to email the user unless explicitly stated in the agreement? **Is there any law governing this?**

Can anyone just make a change and not publish the new EULA at all?

Comment: Why do you need to decomplile it?

Answer (score 1):

If the EULA specifies that changes are effective when made to the document on the web site, this will be upheld in many jurisdictions. If there is no such provision in the original agreement, then at the least there would need to be notice to the other parties, the method of which might be specified in a particular jurisdiction by law if the agreement does not specify it.

If the original agreement does not reserve the right to add or change provisions in the EULA, than any such changes might well (depending on the jurisdiction) be invalid as to parties who entered into the agreement before the change was made.

Making this clear in the original agreement will avoid many problems.